# How to set position to &lt; 5 and mod 2 = 1

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

The xml I have has a daytime and night time, so I need to use mod 2 = 1 to get the odd `dailyforecast` for each set day. But when I do this it is giving me the whole 10 day forecast and I just want to get 5 days. To set 5 days I know I have to use `position &lt; 5`, but I do not know how to imply that with `mod 2 = 1`. Any help will do, hope this is detailed enough.

```
    <forecast>
       <dailyforecast>
         <hightemp>
         </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
         <lowtemp>
         </lowtemp>
      <dailyforecast>
         <hightemp>
         </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
         <lowtemp>
         </lowtemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
         <hightemp>
         </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
         <lowtemp>
         </lowtemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
         <hightemp>
         </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
         <lowtemp>
        </lowtemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
        <hightemp>
        </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
        <lowtemp>
        </lowtemp>
      </dailyforecast>
      <dailyforecast>
        <hightemp>
        </hightemp>
      </dailyforecast>
</forecast>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPATH should work:

```
/forecast/dailyforecast[position() < 10 and position() mod 2 =1]
```

Comment: Doesn't let me use `<`

Comment: But it did let me use `<xsl:for-each select="//forecast/dailyForecastPeriods[position() &lt; 10 and position() mod 2 = 1]">` thanks I just could not figure out how to write it !!

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement that is:

```
<xsl:template match="forecast">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="top" select="dailyforecast[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="5" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- generic TOP template -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="top">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $count">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dailyforecast">
  <!-- format current node (day) and following-sibling::dailyforecast[1] (night) -->
</xsl:template>
```

This works because `position()` refers to the position in the selected node-set. So if you select the odd nodes only in template 1, you will get a fresh position counter in template 2.

Of course you can collapse the generic "top" functionality into the `dailyforecast` template, but then it's not re-usable anymore.

```
<xsl:template match="dailyforecast">
  <xsl:if test="positon() &lt;= 5">
    <!-- format current node (day) and following-sibling::dailyforecast[1] (night) -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```